# how to resolve error :SDL_OpenAudio (2 channels, 44100 Hz): No such audio device

Tags: python, ssl, audio

I have tried the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ffpyplayer.player import MediaPlayer
video_path="/home/xxx/Desktop/videoplayback.mp4"
def PlayVideo(video_path):
    video=cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)
    player = MediaPlayer(video_path)
    while True:
        grabbed, frame=video.read()
        audio_frame, val = player.get_frame()
        if not grabbed:
            print("End of video")
            break
        if cv2.waitKey(28) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break
        cv2.imshow("Video", frame)
        if val != 'eof' and audio_frame is not None:
            #audio
            img, t = audio_frame
    video.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
PlayVideo(video_path)
```

I'm getting following error.

> SDL_OpenAudio (2 channels, 44100 Hz): No such audio device
>   SDL_OpenAudio (1 channels, 44100 Hz): No such audio device
>   No more channel combinations to try, audio open failed

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by installing the latest version of ffpyplayer on GitHub as per the project's [instructions](http://matham.github.io/ffpyplayer/installation.html).

```
pip install https://github.com/matham/ffpyplayer/archive/master.zip
```